# Is it acceptable to nest HTML table row elements?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to make table that looks like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Focus</th>
        <th>Impact</th>
        <th>Goal</th>
        <th>Supporters</th>
        <th>Days Left</th>
        <th>Donation Form</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <tr>

            <td><a href="https://staging.dev.compassion.com/act/preview-fundraiser.htm?fid=1" class="js-campaign-title name-link ">First!</a></td>
            <td>Fundraiser</td>
            <td>$0</td>
            <td>0%</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td><a href="http://staging.dev.compassion.com/services/act/donationformpdfhandler.ashx?fid=1" target="_blank" title="Download the offline donation form for this fundraiser in PDF format."><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></a></td>

        </tr>

        <tr >

            <td colspan="7"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Your campaign has not been launched.</td>

        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I don't think having a tr inside of a tr is semantic. Or is it? How could I do this?

Comment: Does it not render correctly without the outer `<tr>`?

Comment: Browsers are, *by design*, amazingly error tolerant - but that's not a good reason to do this. So please don't.

Comment: I should say how does it not look right without the outer `<tr>`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to solve with the outer `<tr>`. If you are looking for containers you can use `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. But you are correct in that a `<tr>` shouldn't be nested immediately within another `<tr>` however you can nest a full table.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same as @HJ05, use `<tbody>` as a container if you need to group multiple `<tr>` elements.

Comment: It's just that the second row and the last row are one item, so I want to group them together. That's why there's an outer tr. @ZackMacomber

Comment: Your table seems to render exactly as you want it to by simply removing the duplicate row tags. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/1rb5fqge/

Comment: I think I understand the question, you would like to display the message below the given row? So if you have multiple rows and one of them somewhere in the middle has the message then you can add the secondary row at that point rather than trying to figure out what the next row is so insert a sibling row.

Comment: If that's the case, OP needs to clarify in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you have a  tag to much.
Personally I would also use `<thead>` and `<tbody>`, but it is not necessary.

```html
<table>
 <thead>
     <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Focus</th>
         <th>Impact</th>
         <th>Goal</th>
         <th>Supporters</th>
         <th>Days Left</th>
         <th>Donation Form</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td><a href="https://staging.dev.compassion.com/act/preview-fundraiser.htm?fid=1" class="js-campaign-title name-link ">First!</a></td>
         <td>Fundraiser</td>
         <td>$0</td>
         <td>0%</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td><a href="http://staging.dev.compassion.com/services/act/donationformpdfhandler.ashx?fid=1" target="_blank" title="Download the offline donation form for this fundraiser in PDF format."><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></a></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
      <td colspan="7"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Your campaign has not been launched.</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```